# Making loop based off what I can say in words

Tags: core-language, output, printing

I have a list of values a:

```
{1,4,11,14}
```

I want to print out values that satisfy b(1+a) = 0 mod 15 where b are the values from 0 to 14. The output I am wanting is something like:

```
a = 1 , b = 0
a = 4 , b = 0,3,6,9,12
a = 11 , b = 0,5,10
a = 14 , b = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

I am a beginner with Mathematica any help is appreciated

Comment: A HINT. When you are starting something new to you it usually seems helpful to start with a simpler project, get that to work, make it a little more complicated and repeat this until you have solved the whole problem. There are a dozen ways of doing anything in Mathematica. I'll give you a hint to get you started. Read the help page for "Do" and see in that there is one variation Do[expr, {i, {i1, i2, ...}}]. If you change that i to a, replace {i1, i2, ...} with your list of numbers and replace expr with something like Print["a=",a] then see if you can get that to work. Then work up from there

Comment: Please "Making loop based off what I can say in words" is unhelpful.  What do "words" have to do with anything here?  What does "based off" really mean?  Nobody who has your exact question would ever type a query that will find your answers based on your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is concerned about formatting the output is the style shown in the question. I start by generating the list of `b` values using the method given by Mr.Wizard.

```
aVals = {1, 4, 11, 14};
bVals = Range[0, 14];
validate[a_] := {a, Pick[bVals, Mod[bVals (1 + a), 15], 0]}
valid = validate /@ aVals
```

> ```
> {{1, {0}}, {4, {0, 3, 6, 9, 12}}, {11, {0, 5, 10}}, 
>  {14, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}}}
> ```

Next I define a helper function for displayin a list in sequence-like format.

```
sequenceForm[nums_] := Row[Most@Flatten[{#, ", "} & /@ nums]]
```

Finally, I put the results contained in the list `valid` into a `Grid` with the proper formatting applied.

```
Grid[{Row[{"a = ", #[[1]], ","}], 
      Row[{"b = ", sequenceForm[#[[2]]]}]} & /@ valid,
  Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: grid]

Answer (score 6):

I propose:

```
a = {1, 4, 11, 14};

b = Range[0, 14];

{#, Pick[b, Mod[b (1 + #), 15], 0]} & /@ a
```

> ```
> {
>  {1, {0}},
>  {4, {0, 3, 6, 9, 12}},
>  {11, {0, 5, 10}},
>  {14, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}}
> }
> ```

Anything more is formatting, which I shall leave to you.

Comment: my proposal was: `g[u_] := u -> Range[0, 14, 15/GCD[15, u + 1]];
g/@lst` but +1 of course

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {1, 4, 11, 14};
({#, b /.  Solve[Mod[b (1 + #), 15] == 0 && 0 <= b <= 14, b, Integers]} & /@  l) // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
lst = {1, 4, 10, 14}
f[u_] := u ->Reap[If[Mod[(u + 1) #, 15] == 0, Sow[#]] & /@ Range[0, 14]][[-1, 1]]
f /@ lst
```

yields:

```
(*{1 -> {0}, 4 -> {0, 3, 6, 9, 12}, 11 -> {0, 5, 10}, 
 14 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}}*)
```

or perhaps:

```
g[u_] := u -> Range[0, 14, 15/GCD[15, u + 1]]
g/@lst
```

Comment: I like that last one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way: build a list that contains the indices you want (called zeros) and then parse the list to get the form you want the output in:

```
zeros = Mod[Range[0, 14] (1 + #), 15] & /@ {1, 4, 11, 14}; 
Table[Transpose[Select[Position[zeros, 0], #[[1]] == i &]][[2]] - 1, {i, Length[zeros]}]

{{0}, {0, 3, 6, 9, 12}, {0, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}}
```